# Why can't use eval() function with a private variable?

Tags: python, oop

I wonder why it's not possible to use `eval()` function on the private attributes.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        __private = 5
        print(__private + 2)  # Prints '7'
        print(eval('__private + 2'))  # NameError: name '__private' is not defined

A()
```

Comment: Don't use a double leading underscore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: Interesting. So "private" variables are name mangled with the class name ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)). `print(eval('_A__private + 2'))` seems to work. But `__private` is not a class level variable, is it?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp The doc says _" without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class"_, so it is mangled. It looks like the `eval` has a separate scope or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

It's related to the name mangling, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> Notice that code passed to exec() or eval() does not consider the
> classname of the invoking class to be the current class; this is
> similar to the effect of the global statement, the effect of which is
> likewise restricted to code that is byte-compiled together.  The same restriction applies to getattr(), setattr() and delattr(), as well as when referencing `__dict__` directly.

So, to properly use a private variable in `eval()`, it has to be passed in a mangled form, e.g. `print(eval('_A__private + 2'))`